# How to union query in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I try to use this

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$query = $this->db->get();
$subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();
$this->db->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->from('mytable2');
$query = $this->db->get();
$subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();
$sql = ("$subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2");

$rowsdata = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
print_r($rowsdata);
die();
```

when I use print_r(); to see array result but nothing happened.

Comment: Is this PHP? Please clarify in your question, and add [php] to the tags if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: try `$sql = ($subQuery1 . "UNION" . $subQuery2);`